# Rails4 - Query by time hour and/or time minute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a `ScheduleTime` ActiveRecord object, and `time` is of column_type `:time`.

I'm attempting to retrieve objects that match the current hour and minute

```
ScheduleTime.all.select do |s|
  now = Time.now
  s.time.hour == now.hour && s.time.min == now.min
end
```

Can this be done with SQL in a `where` clause?

*EDIT:*

I've gotten closer, i can query by the hour:

`ScheduleTime.where("date_part('hour', time) = ?", Time.now.hour)`

*EDIT#2*:

This is my current implementation...

```
class ScheduleTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule
  validates_presence_of :schedule_id, :time

  scope :by_hour, ->(hour) { where("date_part('hour', time) = ?", hour) }
  scope :by_minute, ->(minute) {where("date_part('minute', time) = ?", minute) }
  scope :by_time, ->(time) { by_hour(time.hour).by_minute(time.min) }
  scope :now, -> { by_time(Time.now) }
end
```

Comment: The method to get the minutes out of the time object is `min` rather than `minute`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The final version looks fine. Just make sure to use `Time.zone.now` instead of `Time.now` as the former doesn't take your application's configured time zone into account.

Comment: Thanks! i plan to convert everything to UTC and back... because timezones are hard.

Comment: TIMEZONES ARE SO HARD, WHY DOES EVERYONE IGNORE THEM?